# Function not getting called Kotlin

Tags: android, function, kotlin, viewmodel

how would I be able to solve this problem? The function below won’t run. I couldn’t see the toast message. I am trying to implement a viewmodel.

This is the onCreateView of my fragment:

```
activity?.let {
    val viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(Testviewmodel::class.java)
    observeInput(viewmodel)
}
```

This is the one outside onCreateView I am trying to execute:

```
private fun observeInput(viewmodel: Testviewmodel) {
    viewmodel.Testlist?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        it?.let {
            Toast.makeText(context, "inside works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    })
}
```

Here is the Viewmodel:

```
class Testviewmodel: ViewModel() {
    val Testlist: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>>? = null
}
```

Comment: Maybe `activity` is null? At which point of the fragment lifecycle are calling this? Maybe `it` is null?

Comment: @Fred I don't get what you are trying to say. Can you explain further? Sorry, but I really do not understand what you are trying to tell me. Thank you for helping me :) Also, would you like me to add my activity's code?

Comment: i updated with some other changes you could potentially make

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thanks I am still trying it out.

Comment: feel free to comment on my answer if you need more help

Comment: @a_local_nobody Ok. Thanks. It works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
viewmodel.Testlist?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        it?.let {
            Toast.makeText(context, "inside works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    })
```

This won't work because your `Testlist` is null (you defined it as being null here):

```
val Testlist: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>>? = null
```

remember that kotlin has nullability (?), which means that the inside of your function :

```
it?.let { Toast.makeText(context, "inside works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

never runs , because `viewmodel.Testlist?` is evaluated as null and then does nothing further.

One change you could do, is to implement it like this :

```
val Testlist: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>> = MutableLiveData()
```

now, your mutable data will not be null

in your viewmodel, you can then do an `init` block :

```
 init {
        Testlist.value = arrayListOf()
    }
```

which will assign an empty array to the value of your mutable live data in the viewmodel

Comment: I want to add data to the arraylist via viewmodel. How would I do that? I tried the Testlist.add(var) method. Then, I tried to fetch the array then use toast to display the text which is Testlist[0] but it makes the app crash. How would I solve this? Thanks

Comment: a quick fix for that is: `Testlist.value = someArrayList` @TechMaxed

Comment: `val example = arrayListOf<String>("1","2","3")
        testlist.value = example`
This works for me @TechMaxed

Comment: no, remember, a MutableLiveData<anything> is a wrapper for `anything` so you are trying to do : `string" = array of string`